# media query wont work no matter what i have done

Tags: html, css

I can't get the media query to work for different widths.

I checked the meta I tried media all media screen and media only screen.

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/slicknav.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document) .ready(function(){$('#nav_menu') 
.slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});});</script>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 767px){
 header img{clear: both;}
 header{align-content: center;}
 section{float: none;}
 aside{float:none;}
 section img{max-width: 30%;}
 #mobile_menu{display: block;}
 #nav_menu{display: none;}
```

I expect the style rules to work when the width changes.

Comment: do you get any errors or it just not work on runtime, and have you got any style at all to work or is it just media queries (I'm assuming just queries but just want to check)?

Comment: just queries i get no errors i use brackets and then live preview so just the queries which is why none of the styles are taking effect

Comment: "@media only screen and (max-width:479px ){
    body{font-size: 90%;}
    #mobile_menu{display: block;}
    #nav_menu{display: none;}
    
}
@media only screen and(max-width: 959px){
    section h1{font-size: 135%;
    }
    section h2{font-size: 120%}
    aside h2{font-size: 120%}
    
}" these dont work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this i noticed you may of had a few syntax errors (If your selector wasn't an id i just assumed it was a class you may have to check that).

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
.header img{
 clear: both;
}
.header{
  align-content: center;
 }
.section{
 float: none;
 }
.aside{
 float:none;
}
.section img{
 max-width: 30%;
}
#mobile_menu{
 display: block;
}
 #nav_menu{
  display: none;
 }
}
```

**EDIT** After back and forth this is what i have come up with that will work for me on the link provided.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/slicknav.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document) .ready(function(){$('#nav_menu') .slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});});</script>
</head>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    header img{clear: both;}
    header{align-content: center;}
    section{float: none !important;}
    aside{float:none;}
    section img{max-width: 30%;}

    #mobile_menu{display: block;}
    #nav_menu{display: none;}

}
@media (max-width:479px ){
    body{font-size: 90%;}
    #mobile_menu{display: block;}
    #nav_menu{display: none;}

}
@media (max-width: 959px){
    section h1{font-size: 135%;
    }
    section h2{font-size: 120%}
    aside h2{font-size: 120%}

}
```

Comment: that didnt work i can just call upon the header without using a class or id and i just tried it to make sure

Comment: What browser and version are you testing this in?

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to include the section of html you are trying to get these styles to apply to?

Comment: http://home.ite.sfcollege.edu/~brandon.trinckes/cgs1820/townhall/mod7/index.html this is the website here i was able to figure everything else but the media query

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look

Comment: im sorry wrong link its this http://home.ite.sfcollege.edu/~brandon.trinckes/cgs1820/townhall/mod8/index.html

Comment: Your missing this meta tag in your header:
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: that was the old one i can get the 479 media query to work but it wont display the mobile menu (correction i can but i have to make it display for the enitre page no matter what width which i do not want

Comment: @BrandonTrinckes I have made an edit to my answer, see how that goes., you will have to check if you need to add !important anywhere else to override existing styles.

Comment: i found out on the media i needed to add a space between and and the ()